# Send multiple flash messages or context for form validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have passport set-up and am validating the input in the sign-up process. One of the validation items is:

```
if (!validateEmail(email)) {
  console.log('Invalid email address')
  return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Invalid Email Address'))
}
```

I'd like to deliver the attempted email back to the template and load it back into the input. The best way I can think of doing this is as another flash message, however everything I try fails to work.

Any way I format the multiple flash-messages it completely drops the flash from the session:

```
{ cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  passport: {},
  flash: {} }
```

Please help!